# Spring - Forbid all enpoints except one for specific role through HttpSecurity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a controller class with 10 endpoints and I want to forbid an specific role to access these endpoints except for one.

I've been able to do it like this.

```
private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST_DOWNLOAD = {

        "/api/exceptedOne"
};

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.anonymous().and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").not().hasAuthority("WATCHER")
            .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST_DOWNLOAD).hasAuthority("WATCHER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

The problem comes when the user has another role that should be allowed to use the rest of these endpoints. If the user has only the other role, everything works ok, but when I put the role `WATCHER` (the one banned) it gets `403 Forbidden` for ALL endpoints except for the whitelisted one but he should have access for the rest.

Please, try to adjust to the solution I need. I know that there are other ways to do this like allowing that role to access that endpoint using `hasAuthority('WATCHER')` but it's a requirement not to do this, it has to be done through `HttpSecurity`.

Comment: The easiest way is to use a role whitelist instead of a role blacklist (`not()`).

Answer (score 1):

Out-of-the-box, Spring Security does not support rejecting access when a user has a single specified authority. However, you can register a custom `AccessDecisionVoter` that returns `DENIED` when the set of authorities is exactly one entry of 'watcher'. The specifics of how to do this depends on how you have security configured (i.e., it depends on what the class containing your config method derives from).

If you subclass `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` and override `accessDecisionManager()`, you can add your custom `AccessDecisionVoter`.

```java
@Override
protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
    AccessDecisionManager adm = super.accessDecisionManager();
    adm.getDecisionVoters().add(myCustomVoter);
    return adm;
}
```